# How to customize the spring UAA login form?

Tags: spring, cloudfoundry-uaa

I was working on a setup of UAA server based on spring UAA with a war file deployed to a tomcat 8 container, the war file(cloudfoundry-identity-uaa-3.10.0.war) was downloaded from Maven repo. However the OOTB login form with cloud foundry logo and the layout were intend to be changed to meet the company's standard.

But I search all over the internet, only find one article about how to change the logo , not the entire form by change the setting in external UAA.yml. Is there a way to change the whole login form? Or do I have to build everything from scratch with spring-security etc?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Never mind. I took a look into the source code of UAA project  at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/ , and I found the login.html inside /server/src/main/resources/templates/web ,then I modified a little bit to meet the layout standard then repackage the war file.

I know it is a bad practice to hack into the code that may cause upgrade issue in future, but it is just a trade off.

Comment: seems the official customization is very limited, see https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/issues/509